# "Network connection closed unexpectedly" only when trying to remove file from repo

Tags: svn, networking, tortoisesvn

I have a problem with my SVN repository. I'm using TortoiseSVN. When I remove a file which was already added to repository and try to commit the changes, I get:

```
Commit failed (details follow):
Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

It is strange, because normally I'm connected to repo, everything else works fine. When I try to commit changes made on files which still exist or just add new files, I don't get this error. It only happens when I try to remove a file.

It happens on my both laptops, which one of them has exactly the same configuration I was succesfully using in the past so it rather suggests problem with repository.

Answer (score 1):

that error typically means the server crashed. perhaps out of disk or out of memory?

Comment: Why wouldn't I get it when adding a file, but instead when removing a file? As far as I understand, if disk space is full then when I add a file, I should have got this error. But it adds properly.

Comment: The server has failed unexpectedly it has encountered something the author didn't expect it's hard to guess what.  check the repository on the server, event logs etc.